# Accessing stat.exisits in a with_items loop

Tags: ansible, centos7

I am trying to create a script that will disable/enable all of the CentOS7 repos listed in `repoList`.

I want to check if the repo file is present first before attempting to edit it - using `replace`.

My idea was to have a 2D list contain the name of file and whether it was present or not. E.g [CentOS-Base.repo, True]

I have successfully created a script that will do this, however it used `include_tasks`. Ideally I would like to have all of the functionality in one file.

I get this error:

```
TASK [DEBUG  Indexes] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'results' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/defaultRepoTest.yml': line 41, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: DEBUG  Indexes\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Exerpt from output from Show results print statement

```
TASK [DEBUG Show results] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
                    "follow": false,
                    "get_attributes": true,
                    "get_checksum": true,
                    "get_md5": false,
                    "get_mime": true,
                    "path": "/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo"
                }
            },
            "item": "CentOS-Base.repo",
            "stat": {
                "atime": 1649670713.3687398,
                "attr_flags": "",
                "attributes": [],
                "block_size": 4096,
                "blocks": 8,
                "charset": "us-ascii",
                "checksum": "70d4820050f582bcbfe1c9726bd32e7df53b1092",
                "ctime": 1649670636.5707407,
                "dev": 64768,
                "device_type": 0,
                "executable": false,
                "exists": true,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 98834,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mimetype": "text/plain",
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1649670636.5697408,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "readable": true,
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 865,
                "uid": 0,
                "version": "1620661251",
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "writeable": true,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            }
        },
```

Code file:
---

```
- name: Enable/Disable CentOS7 Repos
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    repoList:
      - CentOS-Base.repo
      - CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
      - CentOS-Media.repo
      - CentOS-Vault.repo
      - epel.repo
      - CentOS-CR.repo
      - CentOS-fasttrack.repo
      - CentOS-Sources.repo
      - CentOS-x86_64-kernel.repo
      - epel-testing.repo
      - CentOS-SCLo-scl.repo
      - CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo
      - CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo.rpmnew

    reposPresent: []

    enable: 0

  tasks:

  - name: Check if path exists
    stat:
      path: /etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}
    register: outcome
    with_items: "{{ repoList }}"

  - name: DEBUG Show outcome
    debug:
      msg: "{{ outcome }}"

  - name: DEBUG Show results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ outcome.results}}"

  - name: DEBUG  Indexes
    debug:
      msg: "{{ results.stat.exists }}"
    with_items: "{{ outcome }}"
```

I must not be accessing the element properly. I expect the Debug Indexes statement to print a list of boolean values. I can then add these to a 2D list.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. why do you scan for .repo.rpmnew file? 2. where is the state defined (disable/enabled?) 3. don't you think there are better approaches for this use case?

Comment: where is the ```msg: "{{ results.stat.exists }}"``` variable defined ? shouldn't it be ```{{ outcome.stat.exists }}``` ?

Comment: @KevinC 1. That particular repo file is created when you install SCL. 2. The state of each repo is defined in the repo itself, enabled=1 etc. 3. In my question I said tat I have already done this through ansible using include_tasks, but that requires making a separate .yml file. I want to have all of the code within one file.

Comment: Then just copy what you have in the include_tasks to a single playbook. done.

Comment: @error404 Sorry the last line got cut from the output when I pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your last debug task should be

```
    - name: DEBUG  Indexes
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stat.exists }}"
      with_items: "{{ outcome.results }}"
```